# Logging across network using secure connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-sockets, python-logging

so basically I want to do this:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network

But if I'm not mistaken, this happens unencrypted.

Is there a way to do this in a secure(encrypted/TLS/SSL) way?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Logging is regularly done unencrypted and often even as unreliable datagrams for one simple reason: Logging is expensive and that is the cheapest way. It is expected that you have a secure network.

Comment: If you want to eat the expense of SSL, you can certainly do it by subclassing `SocketHandler` and using Python's SSL support - and the same at the other (receiver/server) end.